# Tkinter - Able to view only the last page

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am a beginner in Python and need help with Tkinter.

The below program opens a window which displays only the last page(name of the page is PageOne). I am not able to view the first page(StartPage.

```
LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class Food(tk.Tk):
    def  __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both",expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container,self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)
    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def  __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self,text = "PortFoodlio", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady = 100, padx = 100)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Let's get started!",
                        command = lambda: 
                        controller.show_frame(PageOne))
    button1.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def  __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self,text = "Ingredients", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady = 100, padx = 100)
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Back to Home",
                        command= lambda: 
                        controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button2.pack()        


app = Food()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to _call_ `tkraise` in `show_frame` method. You forgot parentheses. Voting to close as Off-Topic - Typo.

Answer (score 0):

Error in code on line: `tk.raise`
It should be: `tk.raise()`